# How to use ember paper icons offline?

Tags: ember.js, material-ui, ember-paper

I am creating a web module with ember paper where i need to use this module offline as well, now when i use the offline mode the ember paper icons doesn't appear instead just the text appears, can anyone help me getting ember paper work offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any body is looking for full answer i added below code in my environment file under production environment

```
ENV['ember-paper'] = ENV['ember-paper']  || {
      insertFontLinks: false
  };
```

and i downloaded the icon file from "[https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons](https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material%20Icons)" and included this in my scss and changed the src for woff2 file to my local file which again i downloaded from "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v54/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2" .

Comment: Where did you put the woff2 file in yout ember project?

Comment: I put them under public folder in a folder called fonts.

Answer (score 2):

You can [use](https://miguelcobain.github.io/ember-paper/#/) `ENV['ember-paper'].insertFontLinks` to prevent the remote font CSS from being included, at least. You could then store the relevant files locally, though that may be forbidden for licensing reasons.

Comment: thanks a lot @buck, all i did is made this variable false and included the icon fonts in my project.This made it work.